# How to declare a function accept arbitrary length array of rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
void MyFun(MyClass* p){

}
```

Where `p` is actually an unknown length array. How can I overloaded it to accept an array of `rvalue MyClass`.

Comment: use std::array or std::vector, there is no way to know the size of the array by the pointer alone

Comment: @JohnZwinck I never mentioned that I want to know the size. How come that question has anything to do with my problem?

Comment: There is no such thing as an array of rvalues. "rvalue" is an expression category, not a type. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you cannot - since being an rvalue is not really a proper part of the type system. There's no "pointer to rvalue T" or anything like that. Also, because using a pointer means that the pointed-to object could be any subclass of `MyValue` (that is also a reason I would not try something like reinterpreting the pointer as an `std::array<MyClass, 123>`, even if I knew the length to be 123).

I suggest you wrap your raw array in some class (dumb name for it: `BunchOfMyClasses`), and have:

```
void MyFun(const BunchOfMyClasses &);
void MyFun(BunchOfMyClasses &&);
```

as the overloads.